# Array of arrays in vb. Net

Tags: arrays, .net, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have multi arrays as list(of double),  i want to gather  all these arrays in one array and every array have new index like:

```
Arrayofarrays(0)=arr1
Arrayofarrays(2)=arr2
```

What's abest way for that in vb.Net
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can totally have a `List (Of List (Of Foo))`.

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of Double)
Dim list2 As New List(Of Double)
Dim masterList As New List(Of List(Of Double))

masterList.AddRange({list1, list2})
```

Hope it helps. Have fun!

Comment: Thanks,  it was very helpful

Comment: @MohammadBadeeKhatib Welcome to StackOverflow. As a general rule, you should upvote answers which helped you (even if it's not your question it works), and when an answer solves your question hit the checkmark to mark it as "the right answer for you". Also, I strongly suggest taking some time to read around in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), as it'll help you better write your questions, as better written questions are more likely to get you help.